# C# IEnumerable query

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a question regarding this c# code. I can follow the last part  using selenium where it is entering data into the text field. But I have problem in understanding  how this function works  **private IEnumerable GetXlData()** and how the valus are being takenup by **EnterData(string firstName, string lastName)** this test.

I can follow that data1  and data2 hold the first and second column values  but how this alue being returned and being used by the **EnterData(string firstName, string lastName)** test.

```
namespace XYZ
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class readXl
    {
        ReadXLS xl = new ReadXLS("TestData.xls", "Sheet1");

        private IEnumerable<string[]> GetXlData()
        {
            foreach (ExcelData e in xl.TestData)
            {
                string data1 = e["firstName"];
                string data2 = e["lastName"];

                yield return new[] { data1, data2};
            }
        }

        [Test, TestCaseSource("GetXlData")]
        public void EnterData(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("FirstName")).SendKeys(firstName);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("LastName")).SendKeys(lastName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where "driver" is declared? could you post it?

Comment: mate this is a company code.. so i could nt post the entire file.. it is actually derived in a seperate file.. but i can follow that.. i would only need to know how data 1 and dat2 values are passed to EnterData test

Comment: @JohnField This is irrelevant for the question anyway...

Answer (score 1):

See documentation for [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5). NUnit is essentially doing this:

```
foreach (var x in GetXlData())
{
    EnterData(x[0], x[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TestCaseSource` attribute in NUnit is used in so-called data-driven testing. The mechanism works like this:

- Its input (i.e. what is given to the attribute as method name) must be an enumerator method that returns object (`string[]` in your case, but it could be an untyped `object` as well). 
  This object must match the signature of the decorated test method (`Enterdata()`).
- The decorated test method then is executed as many times in a row as the enumerator method returns values, each time with the values that were provided by the enumerator method (therefore these methods are also called 'data factories').

Data-driven tests of this kind are very useful to throw a bunch of different data to a single algorithm, without needing to write the same test code again and again.